# Having issue with pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

I am trying to integrate Selenium TestNG to maven but having trouble in adding dependencies to pom.xml (as described in this [article](http://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html) ), and getting error on the same. Issue appears only when I add selenium and testng dependencies, I have already imported those library to the project. Below is xml code

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>ProV1</groupId>
      <artifactId>ProV1</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
       </build>
       <dependencies>            
           <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>              
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>                              
                <version>2.47.1</version>                               
            </dependency>             
            <dependency>              
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
                <version>6.9.5</version>                              
                <scope>test</scope>                                     
           </dependency>              
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

And this is the error I am getting
[image]
As suggested in some articles I cleaned the project, refreshed but nothing worked out.
I am a newbie to Maven so will be very greatfull for all helpful suggestion on how to fix this.

Comment: I would try to force update with maven or download the jar manually

Comment: Remove the jars of testNG and selenium from your project. Maven dependencies will take care of adding jars in classpath. Secondly, go to `user\.m2 repository `. Search with `*.lastUpdated`. Delete testNG & selenium jars from the result & now download the jars manually, put them in same .m2 location. Now run `mvn test` . It should not give artifact transfer error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by removing dependencies, there was no need to add dependencies. Maven adds them automatically.